# What does this RE match?

Tags: python

```
"token_pattern": r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b",
```

Question 1): Does the '?u' means unicode? Why is there a question mark?

Question 2): w+ means 1 or more words to be matched. Then why is there another '\w' necessary?

Comment: Use regexr.com to learn what an RE is doing.

Comment: For question 2: because you want to match 2 or more alphabetic characters in your input data, and for whatever reason you want to avoid the `\w{2,}` notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**  You are correct that is stands for 'Unicode'. The `(?_)` notation is one method of using regex flags. This is equivalent to `re.compile(r'\b\w\w+\b', re.UNICODE)`.

**Question 2:** As @verandaguy pointed out in the comments, this would guarantee that there's at least 2 word characters in the match. `\w{2,}` is equivalent to `\w\w+`. I don't see any reason to use the latter though, unless you wanted to capture the first character separately. I suppose `\w\w+` is actually one less character than `\w{2,}`, but it's less elegant and more confusing imo.

[Here's a helpful resource](https://regex101.com/) for composing and analyzing regex.